# Count of methods in Ruby just drop during object creation

Tags: ruby, subclassing

Why does the total count of methods reduce, from 81 to 46 while instantiating an object from 'Class' class-objects?

Here's the code I'm running:

```
class Automobile
    def wheels(wheel)
        puts "#{wheel}"
    end
end


class Car < Automobile
    def gears
        puts "Automatic Transmission"
    end
end


limo = Car.new
benz = Automobile.new

puts Automobile.methods.count
puts Car.methods.count

puts benz.methods.count
puts limo.methods.count
```

I guess subclass is not inheriting certain methods, I thought they are class methods, so I did some tests and realized methods displayed by "puts Anyclass.methods" are not class methods. They must be instance methods.

How is this achieved in Ruby, to deter a subclass from inheriting certain methods?

Answer (score 2):

Your entire question seems to be based on the incorrect belief that the result of `Car.methods` is not the class methods of the Car class, but its instance methods. The result of `Car.methods` is the list of methods of the Car class itself. To get the instance methods, you would have to write `Car.instance_methods`. That's why you see that the instances have fewer methods than the classes.

For me, here are the results of running your code:

```
puts Automobile.methods.count 
  #=> 95
puts Car.methods.count 
  #=> 95 (exactly as you'd expect, since it didn't define any new class methods)
puts benz.methods.count
  #=> 57 (this is 1 more than the result of Object.instance_methods.count, since you added #wheels)
puts limo.methods.count
  #=> 58 (1 more than benz.methods.count, since you added #gears)
```

Comment: 1) Car.methods is the list of methods in Car class and it is based on 'Class' class and not 'String' class.

Comment: @pankajdoharey: Yes, that's what I said. If my answer says "String" anywhere, I can't find it, but it should be "Car" at any rate. It said "String" when I very first posted it, but I corrected it in about 30 seconds, so I don't know how you'd be seeing that 15 minutes later.

Comment: 2) isn't limo based on Car class itself so it should inherit all the methods from Car and count should be equal right?

Comment: @pankajdoharey: It is an instance of the Car class, so it gets all of Car's instance methods. It does not get Car's class methods.

Comment: ok just last doubt, what you are saying is that, when i say Car.methods the list of methods produced are class methods right ? and if they are class methods then they should not be inherited right ? but we see methods like new,methods and methods_defined? why is that so ?

Comment: @pankajdoharey: Class methods are inherited by subclasses.

Comment: Yes they are but not by instance of a class. Class methods by definition are not present in instance of a class.

Comment: @pankajdoharey: Yes, that's true. I'm not following where you're confused.

Comment: man i must suck at asking questions, anyways one more try please bare with me.

    so What does Car.methods produce, a list of class methods in Car class ...?

Comment: @Chuck let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3012/discussion-between-pankajdoharey-and-chuck)

Comment: @pankajdoharey: Yes, that's right. Calling `any_object.methods` gives you a list of the methods that `any_object` can perform. For a class, these are its class methods. For an instance, these are the instance methods of its class plus any methods that have been added to that specific object.

Comment: i have really no clue how to ask my doubt.

Comment: Please come over to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250523/is-class-declaration-an-eyewash-in-ruby-is-everything-really-object-oriented this time it may be better framed.