# Is Class declaration an eyewash in ruby? Is everything really object oriented?

Tags: ruby, class-method

```
class Person
  def name
   puts "Dave"
  end
end

puts Person.object_id
```

There are only two ways of accessing methods :

1) Someclass.method in case of class methods. #where Someclass is a class.

2) and Object.method when the method being accessed is a regular method declared inside a class. and Object is an instance of a class.

It follows the pattern Object.method so, does it mean Person class is really an object?

or object_id is a class method? The latter seems unlikely because class methods cannot be inherited into an instance. but when we do something like this :

```
a = Person.new
a.methods.include?("object_id") # this produces true
```

a is an instance of Person class so object_id cannot be a class method.

Comment: In English, question marks go immediately after the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Ruby classes are objects:

```
>> String.is_a? Object
=> true
>> String.methods.count
=> 131
>> Fixnum.methods.count
=> 128
```

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short Awesome.. extremely simple answer. i had tons of doubts, because of this. 

May be you will be able to answer this question too please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249148/what-happens-during-creation-of-an-object-from-a-class-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

Yes, classes in Ruby are instances of class `Class`. In fact, you can create the same class just with:

```
Person = Class.new do
  define_method :name do
    puts 'Dave'
  end
end
```

Then, you can just type `Person.new.name` and it will work exactly as your class.

Checking that Person is an instance of class `Class` is as easy as typing in your repl `Person.class` and you get `Class` in return.